# What is (int) used for?

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and have been experimenting with some example code. Most of it I understand (from implying knowledge of other languages) but something that I've never seen before is `int` in the variable `tempfahr`. To my understanding, `tempTextField.gettext` is converted into a double than used in the equation. The variable `tempFahr` is defined as an int so what is the need/use of the `int`.

```
int tempFahr = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText()))* 1.8 + 32);
fahrenheitLabel.setText(tempFahr + " Fahrenheit");
```

Comment: to cast a double value to an integer value. Note: it rounds the value

Comment: its casting!! double to integer datatype..

Comment: What is the datatype returned by `(Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText()))* 1.8 + 32` ? In what datatype do you want to store it ?

Comment: this is called type casting see this http://guruzon.com/1/java-basics/variable-types-and-scopes/what-is-type-casting-in-java-tutorial-example-how-to-reference-variable

Comment: I think a good strategy would be to make Language Specifications top secret or fake somehow that you need to pay for it - it would soon be leaked and pirated and everybody had one.

Comment: No one is answering OP's question. He **KNOWS** what the cast does, he doesn't know why it's needed here as the type of the result is `int`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes. To show user a rounded data rather than, a mysterious double number like , you have `125.124589 ruppers in your account` :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning result of an expression to a primitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010878/assigning-result-of-an-expression-to-a-primitive)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast a double to an int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143476/how-to-cast-a-double-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(int) is trying fo force (casting) the result of your equation to become a int value so it could be assigned to int variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `(int)` to make the cast explicit, from your `((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText()))* 1.8 + 32)`, which is a double to an int, to fit in your variable, since a `double` has 8 bytes in java and can not be stored in an 4 byte `int`.

Comment: OP **KNOWS** that. He doesn't know why you need the cast here as `tempFahr` is an `int`. This **doesn't** answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

It's to cast the resultant `double`  to `int`.

Probably to show the roundup data to the user, If the result is `12.122`  in textbox it shows `12`

Answer (score 0):

its casting!! double to integer datatype..

Answer (score 0):

It is used to convert type to `int`